# What is this black rod in falcon heavy on both boosters?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy

[image]

There are black rods on both boosters and are connected with each other.One is thicker than other two.What is its purpose?

Comment: All first stages have two of these pipes, one thicker and one thinner one on opposite sides. You're seeing one of the side booster from the opposite side - it's rotated by 180° in order to be attached to the center core.

Comment: Likely one is a pressurization line and the other is a systems tunnel. This picture shows the pressline. https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=41947.0;attach=1408758;image

Comment: Please tell us it is known as the "Jeffries Tube" :)